# Can PouchDB be hosted as an idle Lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, pouchdb, event-loop

I am curious if PouchDB can be used within an AWS Lambda.

The key question (in my mind) is whether PouchDB ever empties its NodeJS Event Loop (allowing the Lambda function to return and be suspended). This would be critical to getting the benefit of the Lambda.

Does anyone know if PouchDB can be configured to only run when it is actually handling a request. For example if it schedules timers for occasional polling this would keep the eventloop full and make it infeasible to host on a Lambda as the execution time would be 15 minutes instead of a few hundred ms.

The purpose is to host a richly-indexed database but which is only available ad-hoc (without a cloud instance dedicated to hosting it).

In the ideal configuration, a Lambda execution context would be brought into existence for 15 minutes when requested, and only occasionally actually run code specifically to handle incoming requests, (and to carry out the replication from those requests to a persistent store), before going idle again. At some unknown point, AWS will garbage collect the instance. Any subsequent request would essentially re-lauch the PouchDB from scratch.

PouchDB in a lambda would give me the benefit of incrementally updated MapReduce views on a dataset stored fast in-memory. I expect to have live replication (write-only) to a second PouchDB whose indexes were loaded on-demand from S3 (via a LevelDown S3 adapter). Between the two, this would give me persistence of the indexes, in-memory fast access, but on-demand availability.

Comment: Here's PouchDB on AWS Lambda with EFS as the backing store, instead of S3: https://github.com/KouchDB/pouchdb-aws-serverless

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, this is looking positive (you can run it in a Lambda) from my investigations so far.

I used pouchdb from within Node to replicate from a couchdb, which ran to completion synchronously.

I followed up with a dump of current IO handles through wtfnode. The only outstanding IO seemed to be the REPL itself. This suggests that there are no live connections or outstanding events after a replication is complete.

Next step is to actually run it in a lambda and replicate data to pouchdb from a couchdb within the Lambda, proving that its execution will actually complete.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. Did you end up getting it going in Lambda and seeing if replication completed?

Comment: If I recall correctly, yes. But it was a long time ago and an experiment I didn't need in the end. I may well get back to it, though.

Comment: For context, I speculated whether the combination of PouchDB and an S3 leveldown adapter would give reads from an index that can scale up more-or-less indefinitely with a singleton bottleneck for writes with no need for reserved resources or capacity-planning as per https://github.com/loune/s3leveldown/issues/3

Comment: A more realistic alternative is to have at least one permanent EC2 with CouchDB, and multiple PouchDB replicas as Lambdas for read scale-out. Note that unlike CouchDB PouchDB doesn't cache the result of the reduce step from a map-reduce, though, which was a concern for some workloads.